# How to insert elements of a list in diagonal elements of identity matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 5x5 identity matrix and a list of float numbers

```
 1 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 
 0 0 0 0 1         L=[0.01, 0.02, 0.26, 0.03, 0.68]
```

My question is how can I put elements of list into identity matrix?

```
 0.01 0    0    0    0
 0    0.02 0    0    0
 0    0    0.26 0    0
 0    0    0    0.03 0 
 0    0    0    0    0.68
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method is extensible to writing the diagonal of other arrays, i.e. `a` need not be an identity matrix:

```
>>> a = np.eye(5)
>>> L = [0.01, 0.02, 0.26, 0.03, 0.68]
>>> d = np.diag_indices_from(a)
>>> a[d] = L
>>> print(a)
[[ 0.01  0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.02  0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.26  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.03  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.68]]
```

Note also that on numpy version 1.10+, `np.diagonal(a)` will actually return a writable *view* that can be used to modify the original array.

Answer (score 4):

On `numpy` it is very simple:

```
L = [0.01, 0.02, 0.26, 0.03, 0.68]
diag_mat = numpy.diag(L)
```

Otherwise, in vanilla python you can preallocate your matrix and set the elements accordingly:

```
diag_mat = [ 5 * [0] for _ in range(5)]
for index, value in enumerate(L):
    diag_mat[index][index] = value
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.eye(5)    # create a 5x5 identity matrix
L = [0.01, 0.02, 0.26, 0.03, 0.68]
x = x * L
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just match the index of each element in `L` to the diagonal indices in your 2-d matrix:

```
for i, val in enumerate(arr):
    arr[i][i] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two easy ways you can achieve that:

you didn't specify how you store your matrix so I assume it is in a nested form
[ [ligne1], [ligne2] ]

with your example as expected output:

```
[[0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0]]
```

first whithout numpy:

```
for in_row in range(len(number_of row)):
    matrix[in_row][in_row] = L[in_row]
```

with numpy there is a built-in function [numpy.diag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help